# How to remove duplicate view results from multiple blocks on same page in Drupal 8

Tags: views, 8

I have multiple view blocks with different info on same page of same content type. I want to remove the duplicate results. I want one result to appear only once on whole page.

How can I achieve that in Drupal 8 ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [Views Exclude Previous](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_exclude_previous), check screenshots bellow

[image: Views Exclude Previous filter config]

[image: Views Exclude Previous view filter]